# DllNotFound Exception - what is the problem?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I faced weird issue - I have 2 lib that I put under `Assets\Plugins\Android`, first lib name is `mylibrary` and second one - `libtetdecoder`.

Then I try to use them with the same way and I see that I can invoke methods from first one and can't from second one, because of this error

```
    (Filename: <d25e5b88a8b44b89b27c70e01a22f338> Line: 0)
2020-09-15 09:39:53.243 26169-26207/? E/Unity: DllNotFoundException: libtetdecoder
        at (wrapper managed-to-native) TestScript.foolib()
      at TestScript.Update () [0x00021] in <d25e5b88a8b44b89b27c70e01a22f338>:0
```

There is how I use these libs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Globalization;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text myText;
    public Text myText2;
    private const string pluginNameFirst = "mylibrary";
    private const string pluginNameSecond = "libtetdecoder";

    //native interface
    [DllImport(pluginNameFirst)]
    private static extern int foo();

    //native interface
    [DllImport(pluginNameSecond)]
    private static extern int foolib();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        int i = foo();
        myText.text = "HERE : " + i;

        int il = foolib();
        myText2.text = "HERE : " + il;
    }
}
```

What is a possible issue?

**EDIT**

Screenshots of both DLLs inspectors

[image]

[image]

**EDIT2**

I find out that it could be possible that my lib has a shared dependency and in this case I need to add these shared libs in alongside with my `.arr` file, I have added missing lib, but anyway the same issue.

There is a `CMakeList.txt` file. It shows how I build this lib

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(pathToOpenCv $ENV{OPEN_CV_PATH})
set(CMAKE VERBOSE MAKEFILE on)
set(CMAKE CXX FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

set(OBOE_DIR ../../oboe)

# Set the path to the parserTet library directory
set(PARSER_TET_DIR ../../../tetavi_main/TV_Infrastructure/Tier1.0/TV_TetFileCodec)
set(PARSER_GWS_DIR ../../../tetavi_main/TV_Infrastructure/Tier1.0/GWStdLib)

include_directories(${pathToOpenCv}/sdk/native/jni/include)
add_library(lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${pathToOpenCv}/sdk/native/libs/${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)

# Add the Oboe library as a subproject. Since Oboe is an out-of-tree source library we must also
# specify a binary directory
add_subdirectory(${OBOE_DIR} ./oboe-bin)

# Include the Oboe headers and shared sample code
include_directories(${OBOE_DIR}/include ${OBOE_DIR}/samples/shared)

set(libdecodersource
        src/main/cpp/jni_interface_tet_decoder.cpp
        src/main/cpp/native_codec/texture_codec.cc
        )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        libtetdecoder

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        ${libdecodersource})

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)

target_include_directories(libtetdecoder PUBLIC src/main/cpp/include)
target_include_directories(libtetdecoder PRIVATE src/main/cpp)

# libtetcodec
set(tet_codec_source
        ${PARSER_TET_DIR}/TV_TetDecoder/TV_MtrDecoder.cpp
        ${PARSER_TET_DIR}/TV_TetDecoder/TV_TetDecoder.cpp
        ${PARSER_TET_DIR}/TV_TetDecoder/TV_TetDecoderImpl.cpp
        ${PARSER_TET_DIR}/TV_TetDecoder/TV_TetChunkBuffers.cpp
        ${PARSER_TET_DIR}/TV_TetShared/TV_TetTexture.cpp
        ${PARSER_GWS_DIR}/GWS_Basics.cpp)

add_library(libtetcodec SHARED ${tet_codec_source})

# Include parserTet headers
include_directories(${PARSER_TET_DIR})
include_directories(${PARSER_GWS_DIR})

target_compile_options(libtetdecoder PRIVATE
        "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-O3>"
        "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-O0>")

target_compile_options(libtetcodec PRIVATE
        "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-O3>"
        "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-O0>")

target_compile_definitions(libtetcodec PRIVATE IS_LIB_TET_CODEC_DEBUG_MODE=false)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libtetdecoder
        libtetcodec
        oboe
        lib_opencv
        mediandk
        android
        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib})
```

So, shared declared next libs `libtetdecoder`, `libtetcodec` and `lib_opencv` after a build I can see that all this libs included in my main lib, nothing missing.

[image]

Comment: As the exception says, the specified DLL import cannot be found. If the first call works and second one doesn't, it means for some reason it wasn't able to find said DLL. Check your naming, compiling, etc. In any case there isn't enough information here to give you a complete answer.

Comment: @Ron looks like naming is ok. I am have not got when did you mean about `compiling`. By the way, which additional information could be useful here in order to find out what problem is?

Comment: Is this happening on a specific platform? Can you add screenshots of both DLLs inspectors in Unity?

Comment: @Ron edited my question, please take a look - `edit` and `edit2`

Comment: you might have missing dependencies? I know for windows you used to be able to use http://dependencywalker.com/ to find them

Comment: @Ron but I don't use windows, this lib uses as unity adndroid ...

Comment: unfortunately I haven't encountered the exact issue as you, try finding a way to traverse the dependency tree of the dll and make sure you have everything included